# How do I solve this Trigonometric Identity?

Tags: trigonometry

I have to simplify the identity 
$$ sec^4x - tan^4x $$
I know the Pythagorean identity 
$$ sec^2x - tan^2x = 1 $$
But I have been told that that only works with squared numbers since it is Pythagorean.
What do I do?

Comment: hint: $(a^{2n}-b^{2n})=(a^n+b^n)(a^n-b^n)$

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck on that for a few hours an that really helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sec^4x - \tan^4x=(\sec^2 x-\tan^2 x)(\sec^2 x+\tan^2 x)$$

Comment: @user2929850 you r welcome

Answer (score 0):

we know that:

$$(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$$

so:

$$\sec^4x-\tan^4x  =(\sec^2x-\tan^2x)(\sec^2x+\tan^2x)$$

Using $\sec^2x-\tan^2 x=1$ we get:

$$\sec^4x-\tan^4x =\sec^2x+\tan^2x$$

But not using that:

$$=(\sec x-\tan x)(\sec x+ \tan x)(\sec^2x+\tan^2x)$$

This is the full real factorized form but we can go deeper:

we know that:

$$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$$
$$a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2 -2ab$$

thus:

$$=(\sec x-\tan x)(\sec x+ \tan x)((\sec x+\tan x)^2-2\sec x \tan x)$$